# Encryption for email discussions involving more than 2 persons

Tags: open-source, email, encryption

I often use PGP (aka GnuPG, GPG) to encrypt/decrypt/sign/verify emails exchanged with a friend.

Is there a similar solution (ideally re-using the same standards) for conversation with 3 persons or more?

Requirements:

- Encrypt/decrypt
- Sign/verify
- Open source
- Clients for Linux/Mac/Windows/Android/iOS

Comment: Without any special client support, you can always simply encrypt and email replies to each member of the discussion separately. In other words, write your reply, then send it once for each member of the discussion. A SERIOUS pain in the neck if there's more than 3 or 4 people in the discussion.

Comment: Why are you looking for an alternative to PGP? I've never seen a PGP email interface that was restricted to a single recipient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use GnuPG.

The [manual](https://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual/x110.html) writes:

> The --recipient option is used once for each recipient and takes an
>   extra argument specifying the public key to which the document should
>   be encrypted.

Of course, it encrypts and decrypts, it signs and verifies, is Free Software, and is available for many platforms.

Comment: So, if I add N --recipient arguments, it will create N PGP blocks, and each recipient will be able to decrypt only one of these blocks?

Comment: Yes. It will encrypt your data symmetrically and that symmetric key asymmetrically for each recipient. See http://security.stackexchange.com/a/8251/55222 for more details.